# Function returning incomplete value

Tags: python

```
def sum_2_array(list1):
    item = 10
    numlist = list()
    for i in list1:
        num = list1.pop()
        diff = item-num
        if diff in list1:
            return num, diff


print sum_2_array([2,3,5,8,7])
```

This function computes the minimum absolute diff between the elements of an array.The error is that it is returning just one value .
Can anayone please check and tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indention. This is not valid Python code.

Comment: What result to you expect for the given list?

Comment: for me, it prints `(7, 3)`, so it seems to work.

Comment: Your code outputs `(7, 3)`, it does not use `numlist`, it might return `None` if the `if` is never executed; it is unclear what it is supposed to do, or why you called it `sum_2_array`.

Comment: `return` breaks out of function body immediately. `numlist` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below code & see if it works. I have Used simple logic

```
    def sum_2_array(list1):
        item = 10
        j = 0
        for i in list1:
            print "this is value of J = ", j
            num = list1[j]
            print "this is value of num = ", num
            diff = item - num
            print "this is vale of diff = ", diff
            if diff in list1:
                print num
                print diff
            j += 1

    print sum_2_array([2, 3, 5, 8, 7])
```

Code you were running in that when it comes to third item in the list i.e 5. At the same time it pops out this item from the list. Because you are using list1.pop(). So it unable to find 5 in the list that's why you are getting only two values. Use code I gave & check if it works.

I got following result from that

```
this is value of J =  0
this is value of num =  2
this is vale of diff =  8
2
8
this is value of J =  1
this is value of num =  3
this is vale of diff =  7
3
7
this is value of J =  2
this is value of num =  5
this is vale of diff =  5
5
5
this is value of J =  3
this is value of num =  8
this is vale of diff =  2
8
2
this is value of J =  4
this is value of num =  7
this is vale of diff =  3
7
3
```